# Dotfuscator FrameworkElement warning

Tags: dotfuscator, frameworkelement

I am obfuscating a Windows Phone project and get warnings of the type:

[Warnings] MarkupAnalysis flagged something in Method Foo.Bar() for the following reasons: uses the name of a FrameworkElement, additional exclusions may be necessary.

I can't find any documentation about this warning. What is the best course of action to correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examine Method Foo.Bar() and see how and where it is referencing the `Name` property of a `FrameworkElement`, if that `FrameworkElement` has a backing member (either a Property or a Field, possibly a Class) that member will (likely) have to be excluded from renaming obfuscation.

Also note that even once the exclusion is done (or if the member is excluded for other reasons), Dotfuscator will continue to warn.

Comment: Thanks for this. Why does Dotfuscator continue to warn? I did exclude but presumed it hadn't worked as the warning remained.